# Fading in and out using jQuery on image change in a gallery

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fadeout, image-gallery

I'm not sure whether my googling skills are rusty, but I've been having trouble with what I assume to be a simple thing in jQuery, but I can't get it right. What happens is that image one is a big image. when I hover over the others, the big image changes by switching class attributes, but I also want it to fade in during transition, but leaving the image thumbnail alone. I have a feeling I'm this close, but I just cant figure it out.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inlinethumbs1 div a img').hover(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('#previewheight1 img').fadeOut(function(){
            $('#previewheight1 img').attr('src', $this.src).fadeIn(); 
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="previewposition">
                    <div id="previewheight1">
                        <img src="Image1.png" alt="" class="previewthumb">
                    </div>
                    <div id="inlinethumbs1">
                        <div class="float">
                            <a href="Image1.png"><img src="Image1.png" alt="" class="thumb"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="float">
                            <a href="Image2.png"><img src="Image2.png" alt="" class="thumb"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="float">
                            <a href="Image3.png"><img src="Image3.png" alt="" class="thumb"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is in jQuery code line 5

instead of

```
$('#previewheight1 img').attr('src', $this.src).fadeIn();
```

get src value using attr of prop :

```
$('#previewheight1 img').attr('src', $this.attr('src')).fadeIn();
```

or

```
$('#previewheight1 img').attr('src', $this.prop('src')).fadeIn();  // use prop as of jQuery 1.6
```

Comment: That is excellent, it's finally working! Only thing is it also fades out then in when you no longer hover over the image, is there a way to override that?

Comment: Perhaps it's better not to use the hover - event, but the mouseenter - event. The hover - event is called every time you move the mouse, mouseenter is only called once, the moment you enter the element.

Comment: That's a very good point. Thank you very much for your help, N0lf! :D